# Hilbert scheme of curves in a degree $d$ surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hilbert-schemes, deformation-theory

Fix a Hilbert polynomial $P$ of a non-plane curve in $\mathbb{P}^3$. By a curve we mean a reduced scheme of pure dimension $1$ i.e., it can be reducible but is reduced. Suppose that the degree of these curves is $e$. For a general curve $C$ in $Hilb_P$ (the Hilbert scheme corresponding to $P$) and a general smooth degree $d$ ($d \ge 5$) surface $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$ for $d \ge e+2$ containing $C$, should we expect that the dimension of the linear series $|C|$ which is equal to $h^0(\mathcal{O}_X(C))-1$ to be equal to zero? (Intuitively I would expect this because in this case if $C' \subset C$ irreducible then $C'^2<0$ implying $\dim |C'|=0$)

Comment: e=1, d=2 gives a counterexample. 

Comment: Maybe you want to assume the curves are nondegenerate, ie, not contained in planes?

Comment: The hilbert-space tag didn't fit here, so I removed it.

Comment: @quim: I have edited the question to non-plane curves

Comment: If I'm not mistaken then looking at twisted cubic curves on cubic surfaces gives another counterexample.  Thinking of such a surface as a blowup of $\mathbb{P}^2$ at six points, the image of any line missing the points is a twisted cubic, and varying the line shows it moves in a linear family.  All that's left to do is show that if we fix a twisted cubic then the general cubic surface containing it contains it as a curve of class, but that doesn't seem unreasonable to me (I haven't checked, though).

Comment: @Huizanga: I apologize for my inaccuracy in my question. As it is clear from my last sentence in the question that the curves I am concerned with have self-intersection number negative which would imply trivial linear series. This happens when $d \ge 5$ and $d \ge e+2$.

Comment: By Bertini (at least if the surface is nonsingular) the moving part of |C| is irreducible, which combined with your statement that the selfintersection of every component is negative would give that there is no moving part. However, there are a couple of things to check: 1) that the general surface containing C is nonsingular, 2) that the components of every element D∈|C| also have negative selfintersection. I don't know how you argue this selfintersection, and how the argument interacts with the choices of general C -> general S -> general D 

Comment: @quim: As far as I understand Bertini's theorem is applicable to hyperplane sections. But $C$ does not need to be a complete intersection in $X$. Could you elaborate/give a reference on how to use negative self-intersection number of irreducible components to prove that there is no moving part of $|C|$?